# Remove a value from Session array

Tags: php, arrays, session

How can i remove a value from session array using a removing link in table.

// in File A

```
< ?php
$_SESSION['cart']['prices'][] = "1000";
$_SESSION['cart']['services'][] = "game 1";
$_SESSION['cart']['prices'][] = "2000";
$_SESSION['cart']['services'][] = "game 2";
$_SESSION['cart']['prices'][] = "3000";
$_SESSION['cart']['services'][] = "game 3";
$_SESSION['cart']['prices'][] = "4000";
$_SESSION['cart']['services'][] = "game 4";
?>
```

// in file B

```
< table border="1">
< thead>
< th style="width: 450px; text-align:center;">Services< /th>
< th style="width: 450px; text-align:center;">Price< /th>
< th style="width: 450px; text-align:center;">Delete item< /th>
< /thead>
< tbody>
< ?php
foreach ($_SESSION['cart']['services'] as $key => $service) {
    echo "< tr>< td>".$service."< /td>< td style='text-align:center;'>".$_SESSION['cart']['prices'][$key]."< /td>< td>ckick to remove< /td>< /tr>";
}
?>
< /tbody>
< /table>
```

Comment: use 'unset()' for a try?

Comment: for example `unset($_SESSION['cart']['services']);`

Comment: better `unset($_SESSION['cart']['services'][$indexToRemove]);`

Comment: but i want to a remove a  particular service and price. how can be it possible?'

Comment: just use `$_SESSION['cart']['services'][$index] = null;` or `unset($_SESSION['cart']['services']);`

Comment: Please Run this code and remove game2 and 2000  and provide me source code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `unset()` for resetting a session value:

```
unset($_SESSION['cart']['services']);
```